# Draw breaklines(dotted line/dashed line) in Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, drawing

How to add breakline(dotted line/dashed line) in OpenCV drawing functions like `cv2.line()`,`cv2.rectangle()` ?

Is there a line type for break lines?

Comment: What do you mean "break lines" ? Maybe read OpenCV documentation.

Comment: break lines means dotted line/dashed line

Comment: @userblock25 So why don't you go and update your question, rather than leaving this misleading text in there?

Comment: @DanMašek don it..but break lines is a correct word in Engineering drawing

Comment: @userblock25 Oh, you mean "[breaklines](https://www.google.com/search?q=breaklines)" (one word). That explains it :)

Comment: yes..its a one word...Sorry...Corrected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opencv rectangle with dotted or dashed lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690932/opencv-rectangle-with-dotted-or-dashed-lines)

Answer (score 1):

If the line is horizontal or vertical, you can do something like this. Kind of hacky, but gets the job done in just a few lines if you don't need anything fancy.

```py
y = 100  # vertical position of the line
thickness = 2  # thickness of the line
x0 = 0  # leftmost part of the line
x1 = img.shape[1]  # rightmost part of the line
on_time = 10  # pixels out of period that are solid
period = 20  # period between dashes
colour = (0, 0, 255)
img[
    y - thickness // 2:y + thickness // 2,
    [x for x in range(x0, x1) if x % period < on_time]
] = colour
```