# opencv polygon with dotted or dashed lines

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, draw, polygon

I have a line of code here that uses the python binding for opencv:

```
cv2.polylines(mask, [pts],True, ignore_mask_color)
```

This draws a blue polygon on image mask.

But is there a way the lines of the polygon can be stylized? Not too much. Just dotted, or dashed, that's it really.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `color` you can use the `thickness` annd `lineType` arguments in `cv2.polylines` method. Refer the [OpenCV docs for cv2.polylines](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=polylines#cv2.polylines) for more detail.

Unfortunately, the only options you can get for `lineType` in here would be

- 8 (or omitted) - 8-connected line.
- 4 - 4-connected line.
- CV_AA - antialiased line.

Not sure why OpenCV hasn't got a direct way to implement this yet. However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26711359/4565943) might help you achieve what you require.

Comment: It's puzzling that this question seems to use the exact same wording as the post you link as "this post" in this answer.

Comment: @Harun Can't believe I didn't notice that. You're absolutely right. This is more than a duplicate question; it's verbatim!

Comment: @Harun   Thanks for replying. I have used the same words intentionally. As the rectangle has the solution, I used the same words for polygon to getting the solution.